# Post contains 4 photos but /{post_id} returns only the first one

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I create a post with 4 photos. When I call /me/home on the Graph API explorer, I get the post_id of the post I created. Now when I call /{post_id} on the graph API v2.0, I get only the 1st photo. How can I get all the 4 photos using the Graph API(no FQL)? Please help.

Comment: Please provide a sample post id so i can help you immediately.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out the same thing. I don't think it can be done outside of FQL.

Comment: Why do you not want to use FQL? I know that it is being phased out but FB will still support it until April 30th, 2016.